# Save csv file from a remote Jupyter notebook to local computer

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, remote-server

I am working on a remote jupyter notebook located on internal server. I want to save my findings/insight on my local computer to make further analysis.

Example:
[Suppose this is the final data I have after analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN7e9.png)

I want to write it to my local disk.
But the code below writes the data to the server's D:\ drive

```
data.to_csv(r'D:\Team.csv')
```

Comment: Are your findings/insight already saved on the server or are they only a part of your notebook? Please specify more details about your problem.

Comment: Hi dsonny,
The analysis is part of my notebook. Since I am working on confidential data. I can't provide the exact information but I'll edit my question to provide an example.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, this may be a solution. Using the Jupyter main page, you can directly open your `.csv` files, and then select `File -> Download`. The files will be downloaded on your local computer.